# Error 500 SonataAdmin: Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer as array

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I get the error "Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer as array" when I try to create a new entity in my Sonata Admin Bundle with Symfony. I didn't have that issue before and I haven't changed anything in the Admin file.

**Environment**

```
Php 7.0, Mysql
```

**Sonata packages**

```
$ composer show --latest 'sonata-project/*'
sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.x-dev 51387ad dev-master cd61e55
sonata-project/block-bundle 3.x-dev 033f4e1 dev-master 64a897b
sonata-project/cache 1.x-dev adb8f3e 1.x-dev adb8f3e
sonata-project/core-bundle 3.x-dev 16c7611 dev-master 3ac1797
sonata-project/datagrid-bundle 2.x-dev 66dcb36 2.x-dev 66dcb36
sonata-project/doctrine-extensions 1.x-dev b07f636 dev-master b969484
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.x-dev b06d010 dev-master 66219fe
sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle 2.x-dev 60edcd3 2.x-dev 60edcd3
sonata-project/exporter 1.x-dev 2aa197e 1.x-dev 2aa197e
sonata-project/media-bundle dev-master 504b500 dev-master 504b500
sonata-project/notification-bundle 3.x-dev e27bbc2 dev-master 84e6c0b
```

**Symfony packages**

```
$ composer show --latest 'symfony/*'
symfony/monolog-bundle dev-master c9fb33a dev-master c9fb33a
symfony/phpunit-bridge 3.4.x-dev 5ddca7a dev-master 9c5da0f
symfony/polyfill-apcu dev-master cec3239 dev-master cec3239
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu dev-master 4aa0b65 dev-master 4aa0b65
symfony/polyfill-mbstring dev-master 7c8fae0 dev-master 7c8fae0
symfony/polyfill-php56 dev-master e85ebde dev-master e85ebde
symfony/polyfill-php70 dev-master b6482e6 dev-master b6482e6
symfony/polyfill-util dev-master 67925d1 dev-master 67925d1
symfony/security-acl dev-master ab4dfe2 dev-master ab4dfe2
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle 2.6.x-dev 11555c3 dev-master d31de92
symfony/symfony 3.4.x-dev 30e3b6d 3.4.x-dev 30e3b6d
```

**PHP version**

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.23-1+020170902060934.6+stretch1.gbpa985da (cli) (built: Sep 2 2017 06:09:36) ( NTS )
```

Here's what my Admin file looks like:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class TeamAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('Infos')
            ->add('name', 'text');
        $formMapper->add('manager', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
            'class' => 'UserBundle:User',
            'required' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'required' => false
        ), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
        ))
            ->end()
            ->with('General')
            ->add('members', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'required'=> false
            ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'sortable' => 'position'

            ))
            ->add('comexAdmins',
                null,
                array(
                    'label' => 'Admin Comex',
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)
                    {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                            ->where('u.level = 3');
                    }
                ))
            //            ->add('title')
//            ->add('abstract')
//            ->add('content')
            ->end();

    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper->add('name');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('name');
        $listMapper->add('manager');
        $listMapper->add('comexAdmins');

        $listMapper->add('_action', null, array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array()
            )
        ));
    }


    public function prePersist($team)
    {
        $this->preUpdate($team);
    }

    public function preUpdate($team)
    {
        $team->getManager();
    }
}
```

This is the Team Entity

```
class Team
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * One Team has One Manager.
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy ="managerOf", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="manager_id", nullable =true)
     */
    private $manager;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="comexTeams", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $comexAdmins;

    /**
     * One Team has many members.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy ="teams", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $members;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Team
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set manager
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\User $manager
     *
     * @return Team
     */
    public function setManager(\UserBundle\Entity\User $manager = null)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get manager
     *
     * @return \UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getManager()
    {
        return $this->manager;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->members = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add member
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Team $member
     *
     * @return Team
     */
    public function addMember(\UserBundle\Entity\User $member)
    {
        $this->members[] = $member;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove member
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Team $member
     */
    public function removeMember(\UserBundle\Entity\User $member)
    {
        $this->members->removeElement($member);
    }

    /**
     * Get members
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getMembers()
    {
        return $this->members;
    }

    /**
     * Add comexAdmin
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\User $comexAdmin
     *
     * @return Team
     */
    public function addComexAdmin(\UserBundle\Entity\User $comexAdmin)
    {
        $this->comexAdmins[] = $comexAdmin;
        $comexAdmin->addComexTeam($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove comexAdmin
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\User $comexAdmin
     */
    public function removeComexAdmin(\UserBundle\Entity\User $comexAdmin)
    {
        $this->comexAdmins->removeElement($comexAdmin);
    }

    /**
     * Get comexAdmins
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getComexAdmins()
    {
        return $this->comexAdmins;
    }

    /**
     * Returns Members ids
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMembersIds()
    {
        $ids = array();
        foreach($this->getMembers() as $member)
        {
            $ids[] = $member->getId();
        }
        return $ids;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the Team entity? It looks like one of your fields is an array and you are trying to render in a non array field type. Comment one by one each of your fields and you will find out which one is failing.

Comment: ¿Can you detect error line in the error logs or error page?

Comment: @albert thanks for your help, i updated the question with the Team entity

Comment: You are not specifying the type entity on ->add('comexAdmins',
                null,...
Add ->add('comexAdmins',
                'entity', .... and let me know if it is this the issue. If it is not add the stacktrace.

Comment: @albert that didn't work. I downgraded Symfony to the 3.3 version and it works again, in my opinion Sonata Admin is not compatible with Symfony 3.4 yet

Answer (score 1):

Add this setting to your app/config/services.yml

```
twig.form.renderer2:
    class: Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRenderer
    tags:
        - { name: twig.runtime }
    arguments: [ '@twig.form.engine', '@security.csrf.token_manager']
```